# Star rating and possibility to remove or change user's vote

Tags: inline-edit, voting, reset

I'd like to add star voting into my project but there is the need to allow users to edit their votes.

My idea is to add a reset button or just (much more complicated) allow a user to hover over stars and change his vote.
But what about allowing users to remove votes?

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: This works smoothly in IMDB - I can't tell why you would consider this complicated. A clear rating button in case you ranked something by mistake (e.g. a occur with a name similar to one you have seen) could be a good addition too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a cleaner look, avoid having a reset button. Hovering (although complicated) is visually more appealing.

For a "null" vote, you can have a 'o' (preceding the stars) which can turn red when selected -- meaning the user has dropped his vote.

o * * * * *

(Many current systems do not have the provision to remove a vote; if a user doesn't like the product, he needs to give it a rating of 1 star.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding 0 to the stars rating is the good solution, hunch.com has implemented it in a very nice way, screenshot below, but I recommend to sign up hunch.com.

[image]